# How to read a text file and display in a text view?

Tags: java, android

When I navigate to a page in the app, I expect the text from the text file to be displayed but it isn't. Am I missing something?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    Button backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    Button selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

    TextView contentText = findViewById(R.id.content_text);
    String text = "";

    try {
        // file to inputstream
        InputStream input = getAssets().open("jokes.txt");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        // byte buffer into a string
        text = new String(buffer);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    contentText.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the value of the string is not null before you call `contentText.setText`?

Comment: I haven't do ne that check

Comment: Your code is fine IF the file is in the assets folder.

Comment: When I debug it grabs the text, just don't know why it is not displaying straight away when I navigate to the screen

Comment: I think the problem is with the setText as when I doa println it displays the text

Comment: If the text is there then maybe there's a problem with your layout xml file.

Comment: IT is the layout, another text view is overlapping. so stupid from me

Comment: Fixed it, it was due to layout overlapping

Comment: is TextView multiline set to true?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is fine, it works as expected. The reason the text could not be seen is because there was a textview layout overlapping the file text text view layout so I couldn't see the text

Answer (score 0):

```
contentText.invalidate();
contentText.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. These type of answers will be deleted from SO.